# docker registry push error

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I tried to launch docker registry with AWS S3 configuration in local.

## Environment

- OS: ubuntu trusty64
- Docker: 1.7.1 ~ 1.8.3
- Docker registry version: 0.9.1 ~ 2.1.1

Docker info

```
Containers: 10
Images: 30
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 50
 Dirperm1 Supported: false
Execution Driver: native-0.2
Logging Driver: json-file
Kernel Version: 3.13.0-66-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
CPUs: 1
Total Memory: 1.955 GiB
Name: vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64
```

I launched the docker registry with commands below.

```
$ docker run \
     -e SETTINGS_FLAVOR=s3 \
     -e AWS_BUCKET=<my AWS_BUCKET>
     -e STORAGE_PATH=/registry \
     -e AWS_KEY=<my AWS_KEY> \
     -e AWS_SECRET=<my AWS_SECRET> \
     -e SEARCH_BACKEND=sqlalchemy \
     -p 5000:5000 \
     registry
```

And I pushed my own ubuntu image.

```
$ docker push 127.0.0.1:5000/ubuntu
```

Then I got the result below.

```
3fd0c2ae8ed2: Pushing [==================================================>] 

196.8 MB/196.8 MB

Received HTTP code 500 while uploading layer: "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-  
`//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN\">\n<title>500 Internal Server 
Error</title>\n<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>\n<p>The server encountered an 
internal error and was unable to complete your request.  Either the server
is overloaded or there is an error in the application.</p>\n"`
```

So could you check whether my configuration is wrong or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you use the docker register v2 instead.

Like this:

```
docker run \
     -e SETTINGS_FLAVOR=s3 \
     -e AWS_BUCKET=<my AWS_BUCKET>
     -e STORAGE_PATH=/registry \
     -e AWS_KEY=<my AWS_KEY> \
     -e AWS_SECRET=<my AWS_SECRET> \
     -e SEARCH_BACKEND=sqlalchemy \
     -p 5000:5000 \
     registry:2
```

Also, try use the `config.yml` approach, [here's an example](https://gist.github.com/kwokhou/f20defbfc34b1bf86c6e6e9e6aa7fda4#file-config-s3-yml) of `config.yml` with `s3`.

Full list of the configuration can be found [here](https://docs.docker.com/registry/configuration/). Check the storage section for `s3` related options.